# How to properly shutdown a spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In order to shutdown my application I used till now the system call `System.exit()`. But it come out to be a bad practice. I tried to throw a RuntimeException instead, but the tomcat server doesn't exit.
The application is based on the flex web client and running under a tomcat server.
Is there a good practice to terminate it? something like `getSpringContext.exit()`?

Comment: How is your application deployed? Tomcat? Embedded server? Throwing an exception only kill current request, not the whole app.

Comment: I generate a web archive that will be deployed within the tomcat folder `webapps`

Comment: context listener should be used to release all the resource so when your webcontainer shuts your webapp, you could release your resources.

Comment: So you need to look for a programmatical way to shut down tomcat, I guess.

Comment: You can use the [Tomcat Manager Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to restart your app. That has nothing to do with Spring, if its not a Java based Spring config with embedded Tomcat (spring-boot). If you are able to call System.exit(), you should really think about adding a security manager.

Comment: The Tomcat manager manages the application with by using the web interface. I would like to have a simple alternative to the `System.exist()`. It is also planed to update the application to use spring-boot, embedded Tomcat, in near future. So I think using the Tomcat manager wouldn't fit now.